# Disable option greyed out, how to disable the app then?

Tags: disable-app

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: Download Manager App Info]

I am having a problem with the Play Store. I searched for a solution, it noted that we need to make sure our Download Manager is disabled. But the "Disable" button is greyed out.

What should I do?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you misread the solution you found. The Download Manager is essential for the Play Store (it is needed to download the apps) and can't be disabled. It's an important system component.

Comment: Give us the link for the instructions that you were following. In addition to that, post a new question about your Play Store issue, if you've not solved it of course or/and no other similar question exist on this site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I temporarily disable an app when there is no "Disable" option](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/130079/how-do-i-temporarily-disable-an-app-when-there-is-no-disable-option)

Answer (score 0):

If its just the connection thats the problem you could install a "no root" firewall and deny it that way. Or , if rooted, find the relevant apk with a root file explorer and rename it temporarily.Reboot, Then do what you need to do, then rename it back again. But as above, play uses download manager to do as the title says!