# App whitelist in stock android

Tags: applications, protected-apps

Is there a way to create a whitelist for apps in stock android?

Ie. I would like to limit what apps are possible to launch, for example by password protecting them.
Anything resembling kiosk modes or family locking is of interest.

If possible I would like to accomplish this without third party apps.

Comment: "Stock Android" is not really specific since each manufacturer can customize its Android and called it "stock ROM" and *might* add this feature to their stock ROM, unless you mean AOSP/vanilla Android. Android itself provides [dedicated devices](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices), though I'm not sure if the use case is suitable for you.

Comment: However, some possibly related questions that might be of interest: [How to disable third-party apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/143560), [Enable and disable system apps via ADB](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56620)

Comment: Why don't you setup a Guest or secondary user account and configure it? Given your requirement I suppose you want to share your device with an another person.